# my button is not visible on the localhost page

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD1X8.png)

This is the image of my header component

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdRfd.jpg)

As you can see there is no button diplaying on the header

Comment: Hello WC to SO, please try to create a reproducible sample using codesandbox or w/e works for you ....

Comment: Use <Button> Cart </Button> (Use first capital) (Link : https://react.school/ui/button)

Answer (score 1):

```
right click and go to inspect and target your button class name why not visible

otherwise check your css file color or bgcolor
```